# any way to use Link or History or redirect in my react module?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

in my projects, I usually call API just like below.

After that, I do check whether response code is 900 and if the code is 900 then, the page returns to log-in page.

each time I write code for axios API call, I have to write some statement whether the code is 900. but it does not seem like a efficient way.

I wonder, is there any way to write below codes to my provider.ts or response.ts. I couldn't write below code in provider.ts or response.ts because of hooks doesn't work in the files.

1. check api response code is 900
2. if the code is 900 then return to login page.

```
...
...
async function reqDelete(id: number) {
  try {
    const result = await apiProvider.remove(
      'v1/history/delete',
      id,
    );    
// if the code is 200 then it works well
    if (result.code === 200) {
      alert(result.detailMsg);
    }
// if the response code 900 then go back to login page
    if (result.code === 900) {
      dispatch(logoutUser());
      history.push('/login');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

provider.ts

```
...
...
const remove = (resource: string, id: number) => {
    return axios
        .delete(`${BASE_URL}/${resource}/${id}`)
        .then(handleResponse)
        .catch(handleError);
};


export const apiProvider = {
    get,
    remove,
};
```

response.ts

```
export function handleResponse(response: any) {
  if (response.results) {
    return response.results;
  }

  if (response.data) {
    //    return response.data;
  }

  return response;
}

export function handleError(error: any) {
  if (error.data) {
    return error.data;
  }
  return error;
}
```

please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

React is a Single Page Application(SPA), which means you can just redirect, which would resolute into reload. We don't want that behavior in a SPA, so we relay on modules like `react-router`. You already tried to use the `history` extension.

Because I don't see your full Project, I just show a basic structure.

App.tsx

```
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const App = () => {

    const history = createBrowserHistory();
    
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <{YourLoginModule}>
          </Route>
          <Route>
             ....
          </Route>
          ...
       </Switch>
     </Router>
  );
}
```

RequestHandler.tsx

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

reqDelete(id: number) {
  try {
    const result = await apiProvider.remove(
      'v1/history/delete',
      id,
    );    
    if (result.code === 200) {
      alert(result.detailMsg);
    }
    if (result.code === 900) {
      dispatch(logoutUser());
      history.push('/login');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

In your Router Switch the order is imported. If you are not using the `exact` attribute, the first matching path will be selected.

If you didn't answer your Question, please comment below.